# capture the Sms exactly before being sent

Tags: android, android-intent

I’m trying to develop an application to do some manipulation (compression and security matters) on the outgoing Sms regardless of the composer application. The main challenge is that I cannot capture the Sms exactly before being sent. For instance the user compose the message body using Go Sms Pro and when the send button is pressed , right before the sms is actually sent we capture it and do the compression and security matters on .
Any solution or replacement idea appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with KitKat, the SMS content provider has been opened up (finally): http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html

To make this work with previous versions of android, you could set up a content observer to watch content://sms/, query the appropriate tables in that database, and then do whatever you like to erase the message before it goes out.  This is just a thought mind you, but whatever you do will likely involve using this method.

Comment: This will not work. Not only can you not modify the content of that provider (unless you are the user's chosen SMS client), but the contents of the provider do not dictate what is sent, at least for sensibly-written clients.

Comment: As is said, it content observer won’t work because contents of the provider do not dictate what is sent the may neither be the same nor even be recorded

Comment: I know you can modify content://sms/inbox, so I assumed you would be able to do the same with the proper permissions and offered the idea.  I am disappointed it wouldn't work in the outgoing case.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, short of via your own custom build of the Android OS. You have no ability to intercept, let alone modify, the calls from an arbitrary app via `SmsManager` to the OS to send an SMS message.